# iOS Swift GMSMarker doesn't remove

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I'm using google maps and I'm trying to remove a marker.

I'm using the `marker.map = nil` as the guide says. But the marker remains there..

I can't use map.clear() because I don't want to lose everything...

Any tip?

```
/// Hide all the markers
    func hideMarkers() {
        let events = viewModel.events
        for event in events {
            event.marker?.map = nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: In principle it seems to be correct. Please post more code

Comment: added the hide events function

Comment: Whats the difference between googles `mapView.clear()` and your `hideMarkers()`?
Do the marker have a map? Where do you initialize the events with markers?

Comment: the difference is that clear() removes the tiles too

Comment: Then you have to share more code otherwise I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Official docu https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker?hl=en

> If you wish to make modifications to a marker after you've added it to the map, ensure that you keep hold of the GMSMarker object. You can modify the marker later by making changes to this object.

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.map = mapView
marker.map = nil
```

So you have hold a reference to your marker. I imagine that you're not working on your marker.

A ugly way would be to call a `mapView.clear()` and re-add all your markers.

Comment: Yeah thats true. But I tested what he did and it works. So his issue has another reason. Additionally I give him a alternative. What's your point?

Comment: That this answer isn't an answer since it has the same code OP has in his question and clear() method belongs to comment area which also there..

Comment: I don't agree with this. Nobody knows if the questions code does work. The comments are from me and for a better overview I posted this answer. But thanks for your feedback next time I will think twice whether my answer has added value. If it bothers you a lot, feel free to give me a downvote.